# If $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)=+\infty$, then does $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exist?

Tags: limits

> Let $f$ be a real function and $a$ is a real number, and let $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)=+\infty$.
>
> Does $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exist? and if not, then why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by existence of a limit but you can say that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If we're being exact, then the answer depends on the context. In all cases, if the codomain contains a value "$+\infty$" (e.g. given $f:E\subseteq\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$), then the limit exists and is equal to the value of the function.

If $+\infty$ is *not* in the codomain of the function, then whether or not the limit exists is subject to a few conditions - namely, the chosen definition of "limit" (there are several) and whether or not the codomain of $f$ exists as a subspace of some set containing $+\infty$ (i.e. $+\infty$ is a limit point of the codomain).

That being said, I think everyone will understand what you mean if you say $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = +\infty$.